# Comparing two survey

Tags: survey

I have a male and female subjects which will be asking people the same set of questions. I want to explore the gender effect on people's responses. I am not sure how to analyze the data of the two surveys to show a regression, correlation relation between the gender and the type of responses. Any tips on how to do that?
Each question will have a set of answers to choose from (multiple select choices).

Example: 
Q1: What do you think about driving fast
a) Way too cool.
b) Dangerous.
c) depends on who is riding with me. 
d) depending on my mood.

Comment: if it is just a simple survey(no complex processing/analysis involved at a later stage)...you can very well use  cumulative graphs.

Comment: @Snowbell what if I want to find regression, correlation analysis, any tip on how to do that?

Comment: correlation analysis is also a promising tool for analyzing the survey data. Just tellme the kind of questions asked in the survey (if they are open ended questions or the questions for which the participants had to choose one of several alternatives). In the latter  case (where participants are to choose one of several alternatives); correlation analysis is as easy as a doddle. Provide some more details in your question

Comment: assuming the latter case, model male and female interviewer as separate random variables say X and Y. The options (alternatives available to choose from) becomes the values that can be taken up by these random variables.

Comment: I would still appreciate if you provide some more details in your thread. Just edit your question and add more details so that we at stackexchange can help you in a better way

Comment: @Snowbell, you got it on point. I was still trying to decide whether to make it open ended or to have them with alternatives. I will make in the form of MSQ. I will update the question to include a sample of them.